# a folder with package name is not created under Android/data

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a sample app (package name : com.test) by selecting default options on eclipse for creating a very basic app. I ran this app on Android device and it has not created "com.test" under Android/data. Why a folder with package name is not created on app install under Android/data? I tried searching in google but could not find anything. I'm not sure if any configuration needs to be set, any pointers in this direction would be of great help!

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the folder for saving some of your app data use the following code... 
this is the sample code which is saving picture after compressing it in folder saved with package name or Application Name

```
  File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "Your_App_Name");
    storagePath.mkdirs();
    String finalName = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
    File myImage = new File(storagePath, finalName + ".jpg");

    String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/" + finalName + ".jpg";

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
        newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

        fos.close();
        //refreshing gallery
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(myImage));
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pic not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```